# Extract several part of the string using R

Tags: r, regex, perl

I keep trying to compile the expression which would extract from the following data:

```
  [4] "00010131 DistanceToPith=15.0; YearsToPith=3; Radius=50.128; CalcRadius=Yes; "  
  [5] "00010131 PithCoordinates=60.919,6.071; SiteId=KO31; "                          
  [6] "00010131 Location=Djerdap, GJ \"Kožica\" odeljenje 31; State=Srbija; "         
  [7] "00010131 SpeciesCode=QUPE; SpeciesName=Kitnjak, Quercus petrea; "              
  [8] "00010131 Personal_ID=Marko Kazimirovic; DateOfSampling=jesen 2013; "           
  [9] "00010131 Name=00010131; Written=2018-05-04 16:53:09; "                         
 [10] "00010131 EarthCoord=E 44 35 N 21 58; Elev=450-465; "                           
 [11] "00010131 Project=Radakovicev magistarski; "                                    
 [12] "00010132 DistanceToPith=6.7; YearsToPith=3; Radius=104.927; CalcRadius=Yes; "  
 [13] "00010132 PithCoordinates=108.974,27.022; Written=2018-05-04 17:09:35; "        
 [14] "00010132 SiteId=KO31; Location=Djerdap, GJ \"Kožica\" odeljenje 31; "          
 [15] "00010132 EarthCoord=E 44 35 N 21 58; Elev=450-465; State=Srbija; "             
 [16] "00010132 SpeciesCode=QUPE; SpeciesName=Kitnjak, Quercus petrea; "              
 [17] "00010132 Project=Radakovicev magistarski; Personal_ID=Marko Kazimirovic; "     
 [18] "00010132 DateOfSampling=jesen 2013; Name=00010132; "
```

just first eight numbers

```
(^\\d{8}), (YearsToPith=\\d+;)) and (Radius=\\d+;)
```

and nothing else.

Beside this, I am looking for advice and the links where to find comprehensive literature for regular expression in R, since the scope of manuals that I have looked at were quite narrow, limited only to explaining the basics with pretty much simple examples.

Comment: Your expected output isn't clear. What is it exactly?

Comment: @NelsonGon the output should contain the first eight numbers of each line, YearsTopith and Radius values if they exist (values with labels). I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `gregexpr` with capture groups in the `pattern` and `perl=TRUE` has attributes `"capture.start"` and `"capture.length"`, which give you the indexes into the input that match your pattern.

```
ind <- lapply(gregexpr(PATTERN, INPUT, perl=TRUE),
     function(r) rbind(attr(r,"capture.start"),
                       attr(r,"capture.length")-1))
OUPTUT <- t(sapply(1:length(input), function(i) 
    apply(ind[[i]],2, function(y) substr(input[i],y[1],y[1]+y[2]))))
```

On your input with

```
PATTERN <- "^(\\d{8}).*(YearsToPith=\\d+;).*(Radius=[\\d\\.]+;)"
```

the output is:

```
 [1,] "00010131" "YearsToPith=3;" "Radius=50.128;" 
 [2,] ""         ""               ""               
 [3,] ""         ""               ""               
 [4,] ""         ""               ""               
 [5,] ""         ""               ""               
 [6,] ""         ""               ""               
 [7,] ""         ""               ""               
 [8,] ""         ""               ""               
 [9,] "00010132" "YearsToPith=3;" "Radius=104.927;"
[10,] ""         ""               ""               
[11,] ""         ""               ""               
[12,] ""         ""               ""               
[13,] ""         ""               ""               
[14,] ""         ""               ""               
[15,] ""         ""               ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
res<-sapply(str_split(s," "),"[")[c(2,4,5)]
str_remove_all(res,"(\\D(?=\\d{4,}))")
[1] "00010131"       "YearsToPith=3;" "Radius=50.128;"
```

Minus the words:

```
res1<-str_remove_all(res,"(\\D(?=\\d{4,}))")
str_remove(res1,"\\w{3,}=")
[1] "00010131" "3;"       "50.128;"
```

Just first eight numbers:

```
str_extract_all(s,"\\d{8,}(?=\\s)")
[[1]]
[1] "00010131"
```

Comment: Pop-up warning that argument passed to stri_replace_all_regex should be an atomic vector. Instead, some coercing were done and output is:
[1] ....\"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\", 1825\", 2013\")"
[2] "c(00010131\", \"DistanceToPith=15.0;\", \"YearsToPith=3;\", \"Radius=50.128;\", \"CalcRadius=Yes;\", \"\")"

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need the eight-digit id, followed by text containing YearsToPith and Radius values.

Try this Perl

```
$ perl -ne ' @x=$_=~m/\S+\s"(\S+)\s+.+?YearsToPith=(\d+).+\s+Radius=(\S+)/ ; print "$x[0] $x[1] $x[2]\n" if (@x) ' marko.txt
00010131 3 50.128;
00010132 3 104.927;

$
```